# Animating lazy load of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, animation, lazy-loading, android-arrayadapter

Hello I was using animation for an ArrayAdapter. I want to animate a thumbnail when its loaded... However every time any thumbnail of the list is loaded, the animation starts for every items of the array adapter. As consequence, the animation of each thumbnail is started 5 times. What do I have to do to prevent starting animation when any of the items is loaded?

```
public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder;
        Video video = mVideoList.get(position);

        if(item == null)
        {
            item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_recommended_videos, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_recommended_videos_textview);
            holder.thumb = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_recommended_videos_imageview);

            holder.title.setTypeface(
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "roboto_medium.ttf"));

            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();

        }

        holder.title.setText(video.getTitle());
        ImageView iv = holder.thumb;
        if (video.getThumb() != null) {
            if(!mAnimationFlags.get(position)){
                iv.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                mAnimationFlags.set(position, true);
            }
            holder.thumb.setImageBitmap(video.getThumb());
        } else {
            holder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummy_video_thumbnail);
        }


        return(item);
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView thumb;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you determine that a thumbnail is "loaded"?

Comment: I called object.setView() inside ArrayAdapter constructor... But i already solved it. See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it by myself, I only had to instantiate a new animation in each call of ´getView()´. Here is the proper code:

```
public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder;
        Video video = mVideoList.get(position);

        if(item == null)
        {
            item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_recommended_videos, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_recommended_videos_textview);
            holder.thumb = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.adapter_recommended_videos_imageview);

            holder.title.setTypeface(
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "roboto_medium.ttf"));

            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();

        }

        holder.title.setText(video.getTitle());
        ImageView iv = holder.thumb;
        if (video.getThumb() != null) {
            if(!mAnimationFlags.get(position)){
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in);
                iv.startAnimation(anim);
                mAnimationFlags.set(position, true);
            }
            holder.thumb.setImageBitmap(video.getThumb());
        } else {
            holder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummy_video_thumbnail);
        }


        return(item);
    }
```